# Shared Preferences in music player

Tags: android

I created a Music stream app that fetch the data from the firebase but i have a one issue in my app when i play a song and go back and come again then seek bar does not shows the current duration . So i think i should use Shared Preferences but i don't known how to use can any one suggest me the code for my music player

```
 public class ViewUploadsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements 
      MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,View.OnTouchListener
              ,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
   //the listview
   ListView listView;
     private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
   private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds;
   private final Handler handler = new Handler();
   CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
  //database reference to get uploads data
   DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

 //list to store uploads data
  List<Upload> uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
  private TextView mSelectedTrackTitle,selected_track_ar;
   private ImageView mSelectedTrackImage;
   private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
  private ImageView mPlayerControl;
  Toolbar toolbar2;


  TextView length;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_upload);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     //status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

     seekBarProgress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.length);

    listView.setStackFromBottom(true);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

   mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            togglePlayPause();
        }
    });
  mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new 
      MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    });
    mSelectedTrackTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_track_title);
    mSelectedTrackImage = 
     (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected_track_image);
     mSelectedTrackTitle.setSelected(true);
     mPlayerControl = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_control);
     selected_track_ar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_track_ar);

         mPlayerControl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            togglePlayPause();
        }
    });
         get();
            //getting the database reference
         mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference
      (Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //retrieving upload data from firebase database
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);
            }

               adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
            (ArrayList<Upload>) uploadList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         }

          @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
     });


     }
    @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

   Intent svc=new Intent(this, MySongServices.class);
   startService(svc);
            }
   private void togglePlayPause() {
     if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
         mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
     } else if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
         mMediaPlayer.start();
         mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
         mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
          primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
              }
     }

      public void get()
     {
     seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
     seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);
     mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
     mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int 
    i, long l) {
            //getting the upload
            Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);
            mSelectedTrackTitle.setText(upload.getName());
            selected_track_ar.setText(upload.getAr());
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);
                              }

            try {
                 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(upload.getUrl());
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                        }
          });



      }

      private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
   try {
       seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) 
             mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() 
          / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100));
       if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
               }
           };
           handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
       }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
      }




   @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if(v.getId() == R.id.length){
          /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer  
            to 
     seekBar primary progress position*/
       if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds 
       / 100) * sb.getProgress();
           mMediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
        }
    }
    return false;


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use android lifecycle **onPause()**, **onResume()** functions to detect when the application is going on background and foreground and depends on conditions you need update all required values.

For more information please have a look at - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onresume